# Create a PNG image that has the same XMODEM-CRC as an exiting PNG image

Tags: encryption, hash, png, checksum, crc

I have a problem which requires me to create a brand new PNG image, that has a same XMODEM-CRC checksum as an existing PNG image.

The new image must have a PNG structure and the exising image's XMODEM-CRC is: `0xC553`

I am looking for a way which i can solve the problem or a solution(image that meets the mentioned conditions).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You asked this before and was asked to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Assign 16 bits in a row somewhere in the PNG file that you can change (could be in a PNG comment), and try all 65,536 values until you get the XMODEM CRC you want.